# Problems to separate data

Tags: r, datatable, statistics, subset

I have the FreqAnual.

`Fêmea Macho`

`Abril         3     0`

`Agosto        1     0`

`Dezembro      7     0`

`Fevereiro     6     4`

`Janeiro       6     4`

`Julho         1     0`

`Junho         5     0`

`Maio          3     0`

`Março        20     2`

`Novembro      4     1`

`Outubro       3     0`

It also comes from a dataset from Excel, in which is the column "Mes", and a row for every register, and another row for sex, that comes to be Fêmea and Macho.

I used the `FreqAnual <- table(Dados_procesados$Mes, Dados_procesados$Sexo)` .

So i tried `FreqJan <- Dados_Procesados [Mes == Janeiro, ]`, also the one with the $ before Mes, and just get the result

`FreqJan <- Dados_Procesados [Mes = Janeiro, ]`

`Error: object 'Dados_Procesados' not found`

What can I do? Also the subtable didn't work

I was expecting something like

`Fêmea  Macho`

`Janeiro    6      4`

I need it that way, so I can do G test monthly to find the sex ratio, and if there were significant differences

Comment: Should there really be any whitespace between 'Dados_Procesados' and '[Mes =Janeiro, ]' ?

Comment: plese see the difference between `Mes = Janeiro` and `Mes == Janeiro`. `==` is the equality operator, while `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: Is the variable really called `Dados_Procesados` In proper brazilian portuguese, it should be called `Dados_Processados`, with a double `ss`

Comment: That's right, my bad about the `ss` . However, i think it doesn't change nothing.

Comment: As is, the question is hard to understand. What is the desired output? What are you trying to achieve?
Please share the data in a proper reproducible format. You may do so by pasting the output of the original data object (not so sure if it is `FreqAnual` or `Dados_Procesados`), as in `dput(Dados_Procesados)`

Comment: The desired output is after the "I was expecting something like"

Comment: please mind R is also case-sensitive. `Dados_procesados` and `Dados_Procesados` are different

Comment: Yeah, also my mistake in the post. But in the R I pick it from the options, so I'm not writing it wrong there

Comment: Juan, welcome to SO. Please take the time to take the tour and go through tutorials on how to ask questions. It may greatly enhance your chances of getting valuable feedback. This link is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

This question is unclear, full of typos, and irreproducible. Make the question clear, remove the typos, include data formated as code (with dput, not as formated tables), and you are going to find your answers really fast.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, what is dput?